# how do i get the product of the inputted values in two edittext?

Tags: android

I want to get the product of the inputted values in two editTexts.
For example I will input [1,2,3,4,5] in xValues then I will input also [6,7,8,9,10] in freqValues then it will multiply (1*6),(2*7),(3*8),(4*9),(5*10). How will i do that? Please help me. Thank you in advance:)

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView xValues = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.x_Values);
    final AutoCompleteTextView freqValues = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.frequency_Values);      

    Button btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      public void onClick(View arg0)
      {      
          String[]x = ( xValues.getText().toString().split(","));
          String []freq = ( freqValues.getText().toString().split(","));

          int[]convertedx=new int[x.length];
          int[]convertedfreq=new int[freq.length];  
      }     
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do some error catching to make sure only numbers are inputted but once you get that figured out, do something like this:

```
...
String[]x = ( xValues.getText().toString().split(","));
String []freq = ( freqValues.getText().toString().split(","));

int product = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) { 
    int tempX = Integer.parseInt(x[i]);
    int tempFreq = Integer.parseInt(freq[i]);

    product += (tempX * tempFreq);
}
```

Assuming that the arrays are split correctly and only contain integers, this loop will grab the first int from X[] and Freq[] and then multiply them together, and add it to product, then grab the 2nd int from these arrays, parse the string into an int, and then multiply those and loop through until the end of the array.